# CSS Image not appearing

Tags: html, css

I have looked in many places to find answers such as a few forums here, daniweb, as well as other similar websites like this that I've found on google, bing, and yahoo, and yet I still can't find an answer. Here is my problem that lies:

I am trying to code an image into the top of the screen (using Chrome if you wanted to know) and I want it to appear as it is the leftside of my banner.

Here is the code:

```
LeftBanner {
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    background:url('/Graphics/LeftBanner.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

How do you suppose I make it show up? If, in Inspect Element, I remove the checkmark for the image, a box with those dimensions appear, so I that is out of the equation. I have tried so many things that this was the last result. Any suggestions or answers are appreciated greatly.

Comment: `LeftBanner` is a tag? o_0

Comment: `LeftBanner` needs to be changed to `.LeftBanner` or `#LeftBanner` the only way it would work now is if you had an HTML element of `<LeftBanner>`

Comment: and remove first slash in image url

Comment: @MichalChovanec Doesn't that depend on site root or relative to document?

Comment: yes with first slash it is relative to site root without to current document or css file, so i think it is better to use url relative to css file

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `.` (class) or `#` (id) selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  .LeftBanner {
        width: 20px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #b0c4de;
        position: fixed;
        top: 5px;
        background-image:url('/Graphics/LeftBanner.png');
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: The thing is, when I add ".LeftBanner" it doesn't even show the solid rectangle. When I leave out the ".," it shows up.

Comment: @hjpotter92 All I put in there that refers to that is <LeftBanner></LeftBanner> but, also, I fixed the problem. I realized that, in your jsfiddle thing, that the png size was too big and unless I made it smaller, it wouldn't fit. Yeah, haha. Sorry guys. I am a very young striving "wanna-be indie developer" but it doesn't help if this website has a upvote and downvote system. I will only get downvotes since sometimes I don't see those easy mistakes. Is there a way I can be safe and still ask questions and just answer questions people ask without being judged on how well I stated a question?

Comment: It isn't all about reputation. You should include all relevant codes while asking question.

Comment: @hjpotter92 So, what do I do to my CSS code to make the .LeftBanner work instead of it just being a LeftBanner?

Comment: You can try `<div class='LeftBanner'>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax, you shoud remove the first slach.

If LeftBanner is a class.

```
.LeftBanner {
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    background-image:url('Graphics/LeftBanner.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

or

If LeftBanner is a id.

```
#LeftBanner {
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    background-image:url('Graphics/LeftBanner.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't put an Image only in CSS you know. You have to start to identify it in the HTML code, create an ID for it (only if you have multiple pictures) and then use the CSS for `absolute positioning` if you really want to. For example, I put the style inside my image tag, but here is what I did:

```
 <img src="http://www.hrtlc.org/images/amput-2.jpg"  alt="Chest X-Ray" style="position: absolute; right: 200px; top: 100px; height: 200px; width: 300px; ">
```

Comment: If it's a bad picture, I'm not trying to be rude, but I'm doing a project on amputation and that's the first picture in my code.

Comment: It wasn't about the picture. I misunderstood the line *put an Image only in CSS you know*.

Comment: Well, it's hard to place an image how you want it just using CSS, you have to use HTML or another program. The style basically pretties up the object you want, it doesn't supply the object.